# DJANGO How to update model value +1 in database JSON on a click of a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**Clicking on update i get a Rest Api Page instead of Updating results in database. Thank You ALL**

Views.py

```
@admin_only
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def subs(request, pk):
    sw = get_object_or_404(Swimmers,id=pk).sessions
    sw_list =  sw
    sw_lists = sw + 1

    serializer = SubSerializer(instance=sw, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Urls.py

```
path('vswimmer/<int:pk>', views.VWmore.as_view(), name='view_swimmer'),
path('deletes/<int:pk>', views.SWGDelete.as_view(), name='deletes_sessions'),
path('subt/<int:pk>', views.subs, name='subt'),
```

Comment: is the serializer valid?

Comment: yes the serializer is Valid

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saving a SubSerializer instance using `sw`, but you never add to `sw`. You create a new object `sw_lists` and add 1 to it. The purpose of `sw_list` is unclear.

I *think* you want something more along the lines of

```
sw = get_object_or_404(Swimmers, id=pk)
current_sessions = sw.sessions
sw.sessions = current_sessions + 1
serializer = SubSerializer(instance=sw, data=request.data)
...
```